# Redhat: Swap Memory Used is Much Higher Than Total

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, rhel

The top command showed the following information:

```
Mem:  132110132k total, 10447536k used, 121662596k free,    76120k buffers
Swap: 16777212k total, 18446744063504593392k used, 10221735436k free,  7056188k cached
```

I'm puzzled by the information.  It seems the state of the server is not very healthy. But why the Swap Memory used is much higher than the total and there is a lot free Swap Memory?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your issue was addressed in a related ServerFault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/730122/linux-swap-used-is-higher-than-total). I would check there, but it seems like you might need to upgrade your kernel to address a known bug. Also, I would recommend searching for similar questions before posting. :-)